# Validación dependiente en formulario reactivo Angular

Tags: angular, formularios, busqueda

Tengo una tabla que cargo con datos de una BD obtenida de un servicio, que tiene entre otros campos:

```
id    nombre    tipo
```

Ahora estoy haciendo un formulario de búsqueda, con un check y un campo input para buscar por nombre y otro check y un select para el campo Tipo.
Se puede buscar por uno o dos criterios, si selecciona los dos check genero una consulta dinámica y busco por ambos campos.
Lo que no puedo hacer es que si por ejemplo selecciona solo el primer check, no valide si el selecciono un option del select, ya que con una opción de búsqueda alcanza, y viceversa, si selecciona el check de tipo y solo chequee si selecciono un tipo, y no valide si escribió algo en la búsqueda por nombre...
Intente subscribirme al cambio del check y agregar las validaciones a mano pero no logro que funcione...
Gracias

Comment: Del mismo modo que añades una validación a un FormControl, puedes añadirlas a todo el formulario

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con formulario dinamicos reactivos, has visto [Angular dynamic ?](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form?)

Comment: y tambien como crear Grupos de formularios en angular?

Comment: formularios dinámicos ya seria muy avanzado, solo quiero hacer la validación dinámica

Comment: Si, grupos tengo creados, los creo sin validaciones, y al hacer click en el check le agrego el validador a su input, pero no funciona...

Comment: Gracias a todos, creo que lo solucione agregando, después de agregar la validación dinámica:
this.formBusqueda.get('nombre').updateValueAndValidity();